# Geany 1.32 What happend to the open file by typing the Location

Tags: 18.04, geany

I just upgraded to ubuntu 18.04.   When I go to open a file in Geany I need to follow the graphical paths and can no longer type a location.  When there are 100 folders in a folder it is easer to type.

Comment: In the file open dialog, press Ctrl + L. A location bar will appear.

Comment: Thanks Jos. That is the answer I was looking for.  You wouyld have got the Points if done in answers.  I almost missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file open dialog, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

A location bar will appear. If you type a path, Geany will even provide auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

I use the VTE (embeded terminal) to open file(s) easily :

- hit `<f4>` to get focus on the VTE
- type :

  - `geany path/to/directory/with/files/inside/*`
  - or `geany path/to/file.ext` (use ″tab` like in a standard terminal to complete path)
- hit `<f2>` to go back to editor : file(s) are now open in tab(s)

Easy & fast !